# Object changed when passed through a constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, tree, field

I'm implementing an m-ary tree where an MTreeNode has an  AnyType element, an int m which determines it's max amount of children, and a nested ArrayList to act as a link to it's children. When I pass an ArrayList of MTreeNode's through a new MTreeNode's constructor, the MTreeNodes inside of said ArrayList also have their ArrayList's changed to the ArrayList they are a part of.

```
public class MTreeNode<AnyType>{

  private static class ArrayList<AnyType>{
      private AnyType[] array;
      private static final int size = 5;
      private int index;
      private int actSize;

   public ArrayList(){
      AnyType[] newArray = (AnyType[]) new Object[size];
      this.array = newArray;
      this.actSize = size;
   }

   public AnyType get(int temp){
      if(temp > this.index-1){
         return null;
      }

      if(this.array[temp] == null)
         return null;

     if(temp < 0) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Index is negative!");
     return this.array[temp];
  }

   public void add(AnyType obj){
      if(this.index == this.actSize-1) doubleSize();
      array[this.index] = obj;
      this.index++;
   }
 }

// *** MTreeNode begins
private AnyType element;
private int m;
private static ArrayList<MTreeNode> children;


public MTreeNode(AnyType element, int m, ArrayList<MTreeNode> c){
  this.element = element;
  this.m = m;
  this.children = c;
}

public MTreeNode(AnyType el, int m){
  this.element = el;
  this.m = m;
  this.children = new ArrayList<MTreeNode>();
}

public ArrayList<MTreeNode> getChildren(){
  return this.children;
 }
}
```

Here's my main testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   MTreeNode<String> testB = new MTreeNode<String>("B", 2);
   System.out.println(testB + ": testB Node");
   System.out.println(testB.children.get(0)+ ": testB's 1st child\n");

   ArrayList<MTreeNode> array = new ArrayList();
   array.add(testB);
   System.out.println(array.get(0) +": array's first element");
   System.out.println(testB.getChildren().get(0)+ ": testB's 1st child after being added to array\n");

   MTreeNode<String> myRoot = new MTreeNode<String>("A", 2, array);
   System.out.println(testB.getChildren().get(0)+ ": testB's 1st child after being set as myRoot's child\n");

   ArrayList<MTreeNode> array2 = new ArrayList();
   testB.children = array2;
   System.out.println(testB + ": testB after testB.children = new ArrayList();");
   System.out.println(testB.children.get(0) +": testB's first child after children = new ArrayList()\n");

   System.out.println(myRoot +": myRoot Node");
   System.out.println(myRoot.children.get(0)+": myRoot's 1st child");
   System.out.println(myRoot.children.get(1)+": myRoot's 2nd child\n");

   MTreeNode<String> testC = new MTreeNode<String>("C", 2);
   array2.add(testC);
   testB.children = array2;
   System.out.println(testB.children.get(0) +": testB's child after adding a new MTreeNode to testB's children");
   System.out.println(myRoot.children.get(0) +": myRoots's child after adding a new MTreeNode to testB's children");
}
```

This results in:

```
MTreeNode@2cfb4a64: testB Node
null: testB's 1st child

MTreeNode@2cfb4a64: array's first element
null: testB's 1st child after being added to array

MTreeNode@2cfb4a64: testB's 1st child after being set as myRoot's child

MTreeNode@2cfb4a64: testB after testB.children = new ArrayList();
null: testB's first child after children = new ArrayList()

MTreeNode@61a52fbd: myRoot Node
null: myRoot's 1st child
null: myRoot's 2nd child

MTreeNode@233c0b17: testB's child after adding a new MTreeNode to testB's children
MTreeNode@233c0b17: myRoots's child after adding a new MTreeNode to testB's children
```

As seen, when I pass array, which contains testB into the new MTreeNode myRoot, testB's children ArrayList becomes array as well. Any help onto what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the static modifier on your children. Declaring it as static means any changes you made on any MTreeNode's instance' children will apply to every MTreeNode. This is why when you set myRoot's children to array, testB and every other MTreeNode's children got set to array as well

Read more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html